# Can't find broken packages on Synaptic

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, grep

I searched for broken packages on Synaptic Package Manager, but it couldn't find any.

However, I know they exist, because I ran `grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` and there were hundreds of results.

What could be the problem? If I can't use Synaptic, is there a command that will remove all broken packages?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt-get update –fix-missing` , `sudo dpkg –configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` ?

Comment: No I haven't. Can you explain what those commands do?

Comment: First execute above command and let me know the final status.